# Regarding nested stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Is it a good practice to have nested stored procedures (meaning calling a stored procedure inside another stored procedure)? Are there any precautions that one should follow while nesting stored procedures? Is there a permissible limit on how many one can nest inside?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a limitation on the level of nesting. From the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607.aspx):

> You can nest stored procedures […] up to 32 levels.

The fact that the limitation exists *might* imply that nesting stored procedure calls too much isn't a very good thing. Yet the maximum level seems to me big enough for one not to worry about nesting calls like 5 or so levels deep.

And indeed, I've never heard that having nested calls in your design introduced drawbacks of any kind, nor have I experienced any actual disadvantage from calling stored procedures from one another. On the contrary, I think, factoring your server-side code enables you to make your design more flexible. Or, if nothing else, it at least allows you to make your stored procedures' code more manageable by splitting the larger ones into more moderate-sized (and possibly logically complete) units.

I do not mean to say that you should always try to factor your stored procedures at any cost, I just wouldn't see anything wrong with your having to nest your procedures if that would fit your design better.

Answer (score 4):

The max nesting level is 32 [Nesting Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607.aspx).
In my opinion, the real downside of doing this is that it quickly gets out of control what SP is dependent on another SP. The risk is that you change something in one SP that has unforeseen effects in another SP. Once that has bitten you a couple of times you hesitate before changing the SP and considers creating a new one that does almost the exact same thing and after a while no one knows why the SP is there or if it is actually being used. Gets easily quite messy.

Comment: Sorry, what *is* your point? I'm just not sure. Is it nesting stored procedures or "almost-duplicating" them that makes things messy?

Comment: @AndriyM - The point is that I think you should be careful to use SP's to implement the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. In some cases, it of course makes sense to have one SP that has a well defined task that can be reused in other SP's but... Nested SP's is (in my opinion) is hard to maintain. Forgot to answer your question. Both "nesting" and "almost duplicating" makes things messy. So in the project I work in we have **no** (almost) business rules in the DB/SP's everything that is not controlled by constraints is controlled in the middletire.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much! I think I can agree that maintaining SPs (especially when there are many of them) is harder than maintaining roughly the same amount of client code. This is one case when having a good and timely updated product documentation is particularly important, and all the more so when not just one person is involved in maintaining SPs.